# How to coordinate with the checkbox and the displayed drop-down list content using ui-select directive(angularjs)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, ui-select

```
<td>
    <ui-select ng-model="selectedCountryName">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter Country">
            <span>Country Selected</span>
        </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="countries in vm.countriesList | filter:$select.search track by $index" position='down'>
            <div class="filter-box" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
                <label class='bx--checkbox__label modal-checkbox-label'>
                    <input class='bx--checkbox bx--checkbox--svg' type='checkbox' value='{{countries}}' name='{{countries}}' ng-model="checkedCountry[$index].checked" ng-click="vm.toggleData($index,checkedCountry[$index].checked,countries)" />
                    <span class='bx--checkbox__appearance'>
                          <svg class='bx--checkbox__checkmark'>
                            <use xlink:href='images/carbon-theme-ui/sprite.svg#support--check-padding'></use>
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                    <span class='bx--checkbox__label-text'>{{countries}}</span>
                </label>
             </div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</td>
```

i have a above td where i have displayed with the list of countries using ui-select directive as i want a checkbox along the dropdown list i have added a carbon-themed checkbox separately along the list of dropdown content.....the checkbox is able to check and pick the content of the list.....

But,the checked checkbox is getting unchecked if i close the dropdown....im not able to able to figure out which is checked and which is not from the checkbox by this behavior....

How can i make the checkbox checked till i uncheck it in this case?

Comment: You have syntax errors, you have not closed your div

Comment: No i don't have @Vivz

Comment: i have closed the div...please check the edited code..thank you..@Vivz

Comment: Try to create a plunker with the above scenario

Comment: Im finding it bit difficult to replicate same on plunker @Vivz